# docker container systemd unit integration

Tags: docker, systemd

I run a docker `app`-container container with an attached `data`-container. To keep it up even with CoreOS host updates I use a systemd unit file as bellow. **I am a bit puzzled to why `systemctl restart drone` does not work.**

Initial run:

```
docker rm -f drone_data;
docker rm -f drone;
docker run --name "drone_data" drone_data sh;
docker run -d -p 1234:4321 --volumes-from=drone_data -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name "drone" drone
```

systemctl unit file:

```
Description=Drone CI (Docker Container)
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
User=core
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start drone
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/docker stop drone

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Why what is? I don't get your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `-d` option, which makes systemd believe the system unit crash and removes the process, which is still running in the background.

Removing the `-d` should work

https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/getting-started-with-systemd/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a Systemd unit for that. Docker already covers that use-case without adding additional configuration.

You can tell docker daemon to restart a container in the event it is existed using `--restart=always` in your `run` command (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart). You just need to have docker daemon enabled (`systemctl enable docker`).

Your command using `--restart=always` would look like this:

`docker run -d --restart=always -p 1234:4321 --volumes-from=drone_data -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name "drone" drone`

Comment: Some processes do not handle suspend and resume very well (which in my case matters), also, I wanted to minimize the dependency on the docker daemon since the plan was and is to move to a OCI solution other than docker, like `rkt` or `mkoci` - both facts you could not know.
Besides that, I just prefer systemd units over docker cmd switches. It is easier to manage, one tool that is also capable to keep docker in it's cage.